# C# errors in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, scripting

I'm having script errors. But first what I'm doing.

I'm making my text colorful, the system should look like this. Every second, new differet color. But I scripted the code and it shows errors. Like:

> **error CS0619:** `UnityEngine.Component.renderer' is obsolete:`Property renderer has been deprecated. Use GetComponent() instead. (UnityUpgradable)'
>
> **error CS1061**: Type `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for`material' and no extension method `material' of type`UnityEngine.Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also the script is this.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Colors : MonoBehaviour

{
    public float timer = 0.0f;

    void Start()
    {

    }


    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= 2.0f)//change the float value here to change how long it takes to switch.
        {
        // pick a random color
            Color newColor = new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 1.0f);
        // apply it on current object's material
            renderer.material.color = newColor;
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: error CS0619 clearly states what you have to do: use GetComponent<Renderer>() instead of renderer, as it has been deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can no longer access `renderer.material.color` directly anymore starting from Unity 5 up. you must use `GetComponent<Renderer>();` to get the component of the GameObject first, then you can access the material from the `Renderer`.

```
public float timer = 0.0f;
 Renderer rd;

 void Start()
 {
     rd = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
 }


 void Update()
 {
     timer += Time.deltaTime;
     if (timer >= 2.0f)//change the float value here to change how long it takes to switch.
     {
         // pick a random color
         Color newColor = new Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value, 1.0f);
         // apply it on current object's material
         rd.material.color = newColor;

         timer = 0;
     }
 }
```

Comment: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "Text" game object. What to do now ?

Comment: MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "Text" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Renderer to the game object "Text". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
Colors.Update () (at Assets/Colors.cs:24)

Comment: @OneARMINAS That's because the Object you attached the script to does not have `Mesh Renderer`. Remove the script from where ever you attached it and attache it to a gameobject with `Mesh Renderer`. Create a simple cube and attach the script to it. it should work because the cube has a `Mesh Renderer`

Comment: This works on 3d object. But now how to put this color chaning script to UI text ?

Comment: @OneARMINAS This question has been answered and your error is solved. Please make a new question for this and provide the link and I will help.

Comment: It  don't work on UI text, just on 3d objects. I need your help. Please.

Comment: @OneARMINAS Create a new question then link it here and I will help. We can't keeep making this longer and longer