# c# / unity - error CS0619 and error CS1061

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am watching a tutorial where it seems to work, but in my case, I am getting these errors:

> Error CS0619  'Component.renderer' is obsolete: 'Property renderer has been deprecated. Use GetComponent() instead. (UnityUpgradable)'  Assembly-CSharp D:\Unity Projects\Unity Fundamentals\Assets\Scripts\ObjectColor.cs

and this one:

> Error CS1061  'Component' does not contain a definition for 'material' and no accessible extension method 'material' accepting a first argument of type 'Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Assembly-CSharp D:\Unity Projects\Unity Fundamentals\Assets\Scripts\ObjectColor.cs

here is the script:

```
public class ObjectColor : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Color changedColor = Color.white;
    public Color originalColor = Color.white;

    void Awake()
    {
        originalColor = this.renderer.material.color;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            this.renderer.material.color = changedColor;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.G))
        {
            this.renderer.material.color = originalColor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# errors in Unity: UnityEngine.Component.renderer' is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764534/c-sharp-errors-in-unity)

Answer (score 2):

A while ago, the `renderer` property of `Component` was deprecated (and is no longer in use). Instead of doing that, you should use `GetComponent<Renderer>()` to get a reference to the renderer instead, like so:

```
var renderer = this.GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

This should also fix your second problem, as you can access the renderer's material(s) like so:

```
var material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
originalColor = material.color;
```